# Paypal REST API payments not triggering IPN

Tags: api, rest, paypal, paypal-ipn

Using Paypal's sandbox, I'm testing the REST API to see how it works, so far it's pretty cool and much cleaner solution than the Classic API.

My issue is that it REST payments aren't triggering my IPN listener.

The payments come out of my sandbox personal account and go into my sandbox business account. The IPN listener is configured via the sandbox business account and it works when I use the IPN tester on the Paypal developer site.

But when I run payments through via REST API calls, the IPN doesn't get fired off.

Is this just not supported in the REST API?

Comment: I've decided to not use IPN with the REST API calls. It seems unnecessary.

Comment: How does it seem unnecessary, I am actually trying to find out if IPN is still reliable for use with rest api?